# eog Image Viewer does not show filename

Tags: unity, 16.04, image-viewers

ubuntu 16.04

Image Viewer ( eog ) does not show file name.  While looking around for a way to show file name I see screen shots on INTERNET that show file name at top of Viewer screen as well as in side pane.  Mine shows neither.  Any ideas how to get file name to display?

side pane shows: size, type, file size, folder, aperture, etc.  But no filename.

'-------------

I've narrowed down the problem but not solved it.  With "Show the menus in the window's title bar" and "menus visibility 'Always displayed'" both selected then there is no display of the file name.  Any other menus configuration and you get the file name in the window title bar.  I think I would call it a bug for the filename to not be displayed anywhere under some conditions.

Comment: On my fresh Xenial system the filename is displayed at the top of the eog window. Perhaps reinstall: `sudo apt-get remove eog && sudo apt-get install eog`?

Comment: I am having the same issue (ubuntu 16.04 as well, I tried the reinstall).

Comment: I reinstalled but this had no effect.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, I have several ideas. There are two other ways to display the file name for browsing images using Eye of GNOME Image Viewer, when the Unity global menu is set as "in the window's title bar" and "always displayed" in Ubuntu.

### Method 1: Image Gallery

[image: Image Gallery in Eye of GNOME]

Go to **View > Image Gallery** (or press <kbd>F9</kbd> key). The image gallery or horizontal thumbnail strip will appear at bottom of the window. Then, use mouse cursor to hover on one of the thumbnails.

A tooltip will appear somewhere near to the thumbnail image, depending on where you position the mouse cursor. The file name will appear in the first line of text with relatively large and bold font.

### Method 2: Image Properties

[image: Image Properties in Eye of GNOME]

Go to **Image > Image Properties** (or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> keys). The image properties window will appear at centre of the image viewer window. The file name will be shown in the first line of text as **Name: FILENAME.png** in the window.

### Better image browsing

For better experience to browse images, use **Method 2** with the tiling feature in Unity desktop environment (a.k.a Aero Snap in Windows).

- tile the image viewer window to the left side;
- tile the image properties window to the right side;
- or whichever side you prefer to see the image properties with file name

[image: Tiling Eye of GNOME and its Image Properties]

Another way to browse is to maximize the image viewer window, then place the image properties window at any corner of your workspace (you can put aside the image properties window for a moment whenever it disturbs your viewing).

[image: Image Properties at top-right corner and above Eye of GNOME]

Either way, it is important to **give focus on the image viewer window**.

Then, use <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> keys (left or right arrow keys) to navigate the images. The image properties window will always stay *above* the image viewer window, such that file name is always visible. Else, you can click on "Previous" and "Next" buttons, should you prefer clicking (I don't).

**Disclaimer**: This answer intends to provide clever workarounds, *without* having to install any additional packages or tweaking hidden settings. That being said, these workarounds do *not* solve the original problem that Unity desktop environment had introduced by having such settings.

Answer (score 1):

Go to <kbd>System Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Appearance</kbd> -> <kbd>Behavior</kbd> and change the settings to match as shown below:

[image: eoc.png]

Note: The auto-hide and workspace enable settings should be non-critical. The others are important.

This has the desired result for me. Hopefully it will help you as well.

Source: Experience and testing Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

Change the window menu placement, and the title will appear. This is normal behavior for 16.04

Go to <kbd>System Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Appearance</kbd> -> <kbd>Behavior</kbd> and set `Show the menus for a window` to `In the menu bar`.

[image]

Comment: I have already tried that setting, but that setting is not suitable. Is there a way to still get the file name.

Comment: @hunch  well , i don't exactly understand what do you mean "still get the filename" ? how do you want it to display ? you said you found images online. Can you provide one of them as example ?

Comment: If the setting is set to  "in the menu bar" the title shows (at least for me). If the setting is "in the windows title bar" the title disappears if the mouse pointer is over the title bar to allow the menu to be shown but otherwise the title still shows.

Comment: @ElderGeek yes, that's the proper behavior. The `Show the menu for a window` options and `Menu visibility` work together. I've set mine to `In the window's title bar` and `Displayed on mouse hovering`. That way I have best of both worlds - title is there and menu is there , if i need it.

Comment: That sounds like a key piece of this answer. The OP may have Always displayed flipped on.

Comment: Well, I need clarification from OP. His question seems vague

Comment: I have put this query for bounty as this query was similar to mine. For me the problem is, I have to go through a lot of images in one go so I need continuous display of image' name with menu bar displayed in the window only. Is this possible for eog ?

Comment: I appreciate the answers, but these suggestions are work-arounds.  Having window display settings that do not show the filename could not be intended options.  You have answered the question "how can I make Ubuntu show the file name?"  The question asked is "how can I make Ubuntu show the file name with Menu in window title bar and Hover turned off?"  I believe this is a bug, not an intentional set up by the programmers.

Comment: Here Serg, Try it yourself.

Comment: Here Serg, Try it yourself: With <all settings> <Appearance> "Show the menus for a windows => In the window's title bar" and "Menus visibility => Always displayed" I think you will find that when you double click a picture file that the displayed image does not have a filename associated with it in any way.  Either this is a mistake, or there is some way to show the filename with these setting applied that has not been discovered yet.  The original question here, as evolved,  is how to show the file name with these settings applied.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I learned some new things.  However, the original question was never answered so I am going to continue to consider this a bug.  Under certain options of viewing the name of the picture does not appear.  That can't have been the intention of the programmers.  Thanks again.

Comment: @user2981989  if you consider this a bug, you can submit a bug report against Unity package on launchpad. However , I strongly believe this is not a bug. Ubuntu has been changing its User Interface lately to make it more usable on high resolution screens , and this is part of the changes.  Couple days ago I wanted to post a bunch of links which suggest so, but since that's not what you ask , i refrained from posting.  You can switch to Gnome in meantime , if you want , and try to submit that bug report